# Binding event to body tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to bind an event to the whole page - html or body tag. How can I do that?

This is what I want to achieve at first:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { alert('a'); });
```

So that doing whatever action with a mouse on the website gives me an alert.

But it doesn't work, and the console doesn't output anything. The whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fdsjfkdsf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Fdjfkjdsf
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() { alert('a'); });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].addEventListener('...');
window.addEventListener('...');
```

But none works. How can I solve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tsgamjfr/

It seems to be working for me

Answer (score 0):

The first example you provided works fine for me in Chrome.

Check if you are getting any errors in your console.

Example:
https://jsbin.com/fepoguceyu/edit?html,output

Comment: Ahhh, I see. It seems that my javascript code is not invoked at all. Why is that so?

Comment: Ah, I blocked javascript in my browser. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding an event listener to the body?

I think the following is how you would need to do it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].on("click", /* code here */ );
```